# Save Workflow in Database

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

All

Is there any way I can serialize Workflow and save in database and load it later on ?

How can I save instance of workflow in database in C# ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called workflow persistence.  [Here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/11/19/windows-workflow-foundation-4-and-persistence.aspx) is a simple example to get you started.  Essentially, when your workflow idles (there are certain points at which this is possible, e.g. a Delay Activity), if persistence is enabled, your workflow will create a resumption point (i.e. a bookmark), unload and persist to the instance store you've set up (SQL DB, XML file, etc.).  When you resume, everything is loaded the way it was before.